# Equality of coefficients in this power sereis

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Hei,

I'm trying to check if the equalit of power series (valid in some open neighbourhood of $z = 0$):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty z^ic_i + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \overline{z^ic}_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty z^id_i + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \overline{z^id_i} $$

entails that $c_i = d_i$.

I usually tackle these kinds of problems by looking at the series:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty z^i [c_i - d_i] + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \overline{z^i [c_i -d_i]} = 0 $$

but I'm not getting nowhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that all partial derivatives of all orders (of the difference) with regard to $z$ and to $\bar z$ are equal to zero and $\frac {\partial z} {\partial \bar z} = \frac {\partial \bar z} {\partial z} = 0$.

Comment: you mean that with $G(z, \overline{z}) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty z^i [c_i - d_i] + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \overline{z^i [c_i -d_i]} = 0$, then $\frac{\partial G}{\partial z} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i z^{i-1} [c_i - d_i] = 0  \rightarrow ~ c_i = d_i$ ?

Comment: I believe I am saying even more than that. If $\sum a_i z^i + \sum b_i \bar z^i = \sum c_i z^i + \sum d_i \bar z^i$, then the $a_i$ and the $c_i$ are the same, and also the $b_i$ and the $d_i$ are the same.